# How to programmatically get a reference to an ICommand inside ArcGIS?

Tags: arcobjects

I'm having problems trying to get a ICommand using the method ICommandBars.Find. The ICommand is there, but it's returning null to me.

Any ideas?

```
    public static ICommandItem GetCommandItemByName(string progId)
    {
        UID uid = new UIDClass();
        uid.Value = progId;

        Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef");
        object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        IApplication application = o as IApplication;
        ICommandBars commandBars = application.Document.CommandBars;
        ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid,false,true);

        return commandItem;
    }
```

The result is always null :(.

I need to get a reference to this specific command because it contains some fields and properties that I specified (a IWorkspace object, if it matters)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are developing an ArcGIS 10 add-in, you might have to fiddle with the `onDemand` attribute of the corresponding command definition in the `Config.esriaddinx` file. I can't remember whether it should be set to `false` or `true`, but IIRC that setting does make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, that's interesting, seems like I remember this working differently before 10.0.  I just did a test and even though the command is on a visible toolbar, another command was unable to find it.  If I set noCreate to false it found it though.

At any rate, instead of having commands find each other, I recommend using an application extension to manage data that needs to be shared among command/tools.  Each command would set a reference the extension in ICommand.Oncreate.

Comment: humn, this is very very puzzling. If i set noCreate to false the command gets duplicated :/. Darn, ArcObjects is fun but terrible when this sort of issue happens! I will look into App Extensions Kirk. Thanks. Actually Kirk, setting noCreate to false makes it work indeed and it did not duplicated my command on screen.

5th edit: actually this creates a brand new Icommand, though hidden, has different properties of the one on screen. argh!

Comment: Even if you get it figured out, there's still the risk that the same command might appear on some other toolbar somewhere.  I guess you could find the toolbar, then loop through its commands.  Still, I think an IExtension is the way to go.

Comment: Humn, that is true. I'll look into it. Doesn't seem much work after all.

Comment: I suspect this might be related to the new addin architecture, where commands (and other components) are populated from the XML definitions, but instantiated in a delayed fashion, i.e. when they are first used, to improve applicaton startup time. Does the command you search for come from an addin? Even if it does not, chances are a similar mechanism (using some form of caching) has been newly employed for classical COM ICommands as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record.

I did implement my own extension, and since it's so ligthweight I did not bother to make configurable or a JIT extension.

It's a plain extension and it worked fine. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful :

```
public static ICommandItem GetCommandItemByName(string progId)
    {
        UID uid = new UIDClass();
        uid.Value = progId;

        Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriFramework.AppRef");
        object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        IApplication application = o as IApplication;
        ICommandBars commandBars = application.Document.CommandBars;
        ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid);

        return commandItem;
    }
```